# inserting char into a string in asc order by binary seach

Tags: string, node.js, insertion

I have some problem with insertion a char into an string in ascending order.

for example

```
str = ""
insert c
str = "c"
insert a
str = "ac"
insert d
str="acd"

etc.
```

I need to implement it with binary search, so find the place where to put by binary search, then put it.

If you know some good snippet to use, I would appreciate.

Comment: And your problem is, you don't want to do this?

Comment: @Jongware, I am looking for an elegant solution to do so, my code is cumbersome. I assume there are should be some clear template.

Comment: you should iterate every char in string to find the ascii value each char and insert the char into position wear it fits.